# Attachments not sending through phpmailer

Tags: php, javascript, upload, phpmailer

I am using the following code to send an email with multiple attachments using phpmailer. Email is sended, but with no attachment. I don't know why. No error comes .

```
   <?php 
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {  
include "class.phpmailer.php";
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$From = "madeeha.rehman5@gmail.com";
$FromName = "madhya";

$To = "madeeha.rehman5@gmail.com";
$ToName = "To Name";

$Subject = "hello";
$Body = "Hy, hello";

   $numFiles = count(array_filter($_FILES['attachment']['name']));
for ($i = 0; $i < $numFiles; ++$i) 
{
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i], $_FILES['attachment']
    ['name']);
}

$mail->From = $From;
$mail->FromName = $FromName;
$mail->AddAddress($To , $ToName);
$mail->WordWrap = 50;               // set word wrap
$mail->Priority = 1; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);  
$mail->Subject  =  $Subject;
$mail->Body     =  $Body;

if(!$mail->Send())
{   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;}
else 
$mail->Send();
echo ("Message is sent");
  }
  ?>
```

A java script function i am using is:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var upload_number = 1;
    var attachmentlimit = 5;
   function addFileInput() {

var d = document.createElement("div");
var file = document.createElement("input");
file.setAttribute("type", "file");
file.setAttribute("name", "attachment[]");
d.appendChild(file);
document.getElementById("moreUploads").appendChild(d);
upload_number++;
if(upload_number == attachmentlimit) {
      document.getElementById('moreUploadsLink').style.display='none';
    }

  }
  </script>
```

And

```
   <input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="attachment" size="30"
   onchange="document.getElementById('moreUploadsLink').style.display = 'block';" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [phpmailer dont send Multiple Attachments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965707/phpmailer-dont-send-multiple-attachments) - Please do not duplicate questions, improve the existing one instead.

Comment: I had this same problem... and fixed it... but I don't remember how. I think I had to upgrade to the newer version of PHPMailer.